# Check lifecycle before navigating in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle, jetpack-compose-navigation

So in one Compose sample by Google I noticed that they check if lifecycle is resumed before navigating between composable screens:

```
// In order to discard duplicated navigation events, we check the Lifecycle
if (from.lifecycleIsResumed()) {
    navController.navigate("${MainDestinations.COURSE_DETAIL_ROUTE}/$newCourseId")
}

/**
 * If the lifecycle is not resumed it means this NavBackStackEntry already processed a nav event.
 *
 * This is used to de-duplicate navigation events.
 */
private fun NavBackStackEntry.lifecycleIsResumed() =
    this.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
```

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/example/owl/ui/NavGraph.kt#L122

Seems all other samples don't have it and the same for `nowinandroid`, also I don't think docs have it as well.

Is it still relevant? Should we use it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code you referenced the error [#456 (Simultaneous taps navigate multiple times)](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/issues/456).

> If multiple items are tapped at the same time, 2 or more detail
> screens can be launched. This isn't necessarily a uniquely Jetpack
> Compose issue, as this plagues a lot of non-Jetpack Compose apps, but
> I'd be very interesting to see what the "correct" way to handle it is
> in the Compose world.

The error is resolved by checking the lifecycle status of the app:

```kotlin
/**
 * If the lifecycle is not resumed it means this NavBackStackEntry already processed a nav event.
 *
 * This is used to de-duplicate navigation events.
 */
private fun NavBackStackEntry.lifecycleIsResumed() =
    this.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
```

**Is it still relevant?** Yes, at least personally I haven't found any changelog where they implemented it in their release.

**Should we use it or not?** If your goal is not to navigate to multiple destinations, yes.

Comment: so I guess I can use just `currentBackStackEntry?.lifecycleIsResumed()` within `NavController` scope so there is no need to pass `from: NavBackStackEntry` parameter

Comment: Yes, I think you can proceed without any problems.